# tkinter: Open a new window with a button prompt

Tags: python, button, tkinter, window

How would I be able to open a new window by the user pressing a button in a tkinter GUI? I only need quite simple solutions, and if the code could be explained as well that would be great.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself, and if you did could you please edit your question to contain the code

Comment: Seems like you have two questions here. "How do I make something happen in response to a button click?". Assign a function to the button's `command` attribute, or use the `bind` method. "How do I make a new window?" Use the `Toplevel` widget.

Comment: What is the Toplevel widget?

Comment: @EddyLoring from what I understand, a `TopLevel` widget is a pop up window

Comment: But how would I be able to use it in order to make a new window? I don't understand how to use it

Answer (score 30):

Here's the nearly shortest possible solution to your question. The solution works in **python 3.x**. For **python 2.x** change the `import` to `Tkinter` rather than `tkinter` (the difference being the capitalization):

```
import tkinter as tk
#import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2
    
def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is definitely not what I recommend as an example of good coding style, but it illustrates the basic concepts: a button with a command, and a function that creates a window.

Comment: I tried this solution, it works but I have the second window which uses grid.. And thus this err `TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pac`

Comment: @AvinashRaj You cannot use both .pack() and .grid() in same code. change your .pack() to .grid()

Comment: How Do I add more features to the new window?

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh: use `window` as the master for additional widgets.