# Multiple Windows using Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a school project and I need to create my GUI soon and I cant find an efficient way to do so and I need to make a ceaser Cipher button which brings up a window with an input in there and I need it all to look nice. Here is my code for now. Its not finished and needs to be finished but don't know how to?

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("180x135")


 class Welcome:
   def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.button1 = Button(topFrame, text ="Decrypter Mode", bg='Black', fg="red", command = self.new_window)
    self.button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.quitButton = Button(frame, bg='black', fg='white', text='Quit', command=master.destroy)
    self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

def new_window(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)








topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

one = Label(root, text='Welcome to Crypto-coder', bg='black', fg='white')
one.pack(fill=X)

one = Label(root, text='', bg='black', fg='white')
one.pack(fill=X,)

one = Label(root, text='', bg='black', fg='white')
one.pack(fill=X,)

one = Label(root, text='', bg='black', fg='white')
one.pack(fill=X,)




button1 = Button(topFrame, text ="Decrypter Mode", bg='Black', fg="red",)
button2 = Button(topFrame, text ="Encoder Mode", bg='black', fg="blue")

button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)


W=Welcome(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I had to move some things for the code to show so you may have to fix it if you try it.

Comment: reference to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/python-tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt

Comment: but how do I add to the window though which pops up?

Comment: Add an Entry in the new_window function, and a button in the same window which will get the Entry's contents when clicked and store it in a class instance variable/object so you can access it throughout the class, and then destroy self.newWindow.