# How to open a new window by clicking a button using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a gui application in python for that I was making this type of code.
I have already tired many codes but i was not able to make it up to the requirement.

Comment: Please add your code which will reflect your effort and post errors you have encountered.

Answer (score 2):

What's stopping you from doing it, please refer the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/python-tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt). But basic code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```