# Python/Tkinter - new window command

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to open a window by clicking on a submenu button, but I can't, I saw some videos and posts, but I was unsuccessful in adding any of the commands. I'm using Python and Tkinter.

Below is the source code:

```
from tkinter import *


ftela = Tk()
ftela.state("zoomed")
ftela.title("OMNIA v0")
menu = Menu(ftela)
ftela.config(menu=menu)


##-----------------##
##     LABELS      ##
##-----------------##

mylabel = LabelFrame(ftela, text="teste")
mylabel.place(x=10, y=10, width=300, height=150)

l_teste = Label(ftela, text="teste")
l_teste.place(x=15, y=30)
e_teste = Entry(ftela)
e_teste.place(x=100, y=30)

##-----------------##
##     SUBMENU     ##
##-----------------##

subMenu1=Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Cadastro", menu=subMenu1)
subMenu1.add_command(label="Empresas")
subMenu1.add_command(label="Usuários")
subMenu1.add_separator()
subMenu1.add_command(label="Bancos/Caixas")
subMenu1.add_command(label="Contas")


##-----------------##
##     MAINLOOP    ##
##-----------------##

ftela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python tkinter open a new window with a button prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/python-tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt)

Comment: Where does your code try to open a new window?

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i managed using this function:

```
def new_window():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("800x600+275+75")
    newWindow.resizable(height=False, width=False)

    newWindow = LabelFrame(newWindow, text="sex")
    newWindow.place(x=10, y=10, width=675, height=400)
```