# How to show image with lines plotted over the image on tkinter window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This program reads an image which is in location C:/Square.png and lines are plotted over it. The plot title is also defined. I want to show this whole image in tkinter window. How do I do it?

This is the image. The name has to be changed and we can run the code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIyQ.jpg

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, n_x, n_y):
    y_start, y_end = 100, 425
    x_start, x_end = 25, 400

    img = plt.imread("C:/Square.png") #Please change the location
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(img)

    x_interval = (x_end - x_start)/n_x*2

    h_x = range(x_start, x_end, 5)
    for i in range(0,int(n_y)):
        if i != 0:
            ax.plot(h_x, [y_start + (y_end-y_start)/n_y*i]*len(h_x), '--', linewidth=5, color='firebrick')
    plt.title(str(int(n_x*n_y)) + ' ABCD\n'+'TYUI:'+str(opt_w)+', Yummy:'+str(opt_h))

def get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a):
    x = 1
    if max_w < PL:
        x = math.ceil(PL / max_w)
    cost_rest = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t + min_t) / 2 + cost_a * PH * x

    cost_y = float("inf")
    y = None
    if min_h == 0:
        min_h = 1
    for i in range(math.ceil(PH / max_h), math.floor(PH / min_h)+1):
        tmp_cost = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t - min_t) / 2 / i + cost_a * PL * i
        if tmp_cost < cost_y:
            cost_y = tmp_cost
            y = i

    opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost = PL/x, PH/y, cost_rest + cost_y
    plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, x, y)
    return opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost

PL=30
PH=10
min_t=0.1
max_t=0.3
cost_m=0.1
cost_a=0.1
min_w=0.5
min_h=0.5
max_w=4
max_h=3

get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a)
```

Comment: Do you want to embed your image in another tk window or do you just want to display your plot?

Comment: @pask just want to display the image with the plotted lines in a pop up window

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt

Comment: @AnilKumar i don't know how this would solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add plt.show()

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Tkagg")

def plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, n_x, n_y):
    y_start, y_end = 100, 425
    x_start, x_end = 25, 400

    img = plt.imread("C:/Square.png") #Please change the location
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(img)

    x_interval = (x_end - x_start)/n_x*2

    h_x = range(x_start, x_end, 5)
    for i in range(0,int(n_y)):
        if i != 0:
            ax.plot(h_x, [y_start + (y_end-y_start)/n_y*i]*len(h_x), '--', linewidth=5, color='firebrick')
    plt.title(str(int(n_x*n_y)) + ' ABCD\n'+'TYUI:'+str(opt_w)+', Yummy:'+str(opt_h))
    plt.show()

def get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a):
    x = 1
    if max_w < PL:
        x = math.ceil(PL / max_w)
    cost_rest = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t + min_t) / 2 + cost_a * PH * x

    cost_y = float("inf")
    y = None
    if min_h == 0:
        min_h = 1
    for i in range(math.ceil(PH / max_h), math.floor(PH / min_h)+1):
        tmp_cost = cost_m * PL * PH * (max_t - min_t) / 2 / i + cost_a * PL * i
        if tmp_cost < cost_y:
            cost_y = tmp_cost
            y = i

    opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost = PL/x, PH/y, cost_rest + cost_y
    plot_output(opt_w, opt_h, x, y)
    return opt_w, opt_h, opt_cost

PL=30
PH=10
min_t=0.1
max_t=0.3
cost_m=0.1
cost_a=0.1
min_w=0.5
min_h=0.5
max_w=4
max_h=3

get_get(min_w, min_h, max_w, max_h, PL, PH, min_t, max_t, cost_m, cost_a)
```

Edit: I forgot to change the backend to tkinter

Comment: I meant on a tkinter window.