# How to call one window to another using python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i creating simple login form using python.if the username and password correct it should redirect to the main form. but i don't how to call the second form. i have two pages how to call the main.py i attached code below what i tried so far

**Login.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
        
        
def Ok():
     uname = e1.get()
     password = e2.get()
        
     if(uname == "" and password == "") :
           messagebox.showinfo("", "Blank Not allowed")
        
        
     elif(uname == "Admin" and password == "123"):        
           messagebox.showinfo("","Login Success")
           root.destroy()
        
     else :
           messagebox.showinfo("","Incorrent Username and Password")
root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("300x200")
global e1
global e2
        
Label(root, text="UserName").place(x=10, y=10)
Label(root, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)
        
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=140, y=10)
        
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.place(x=140, y=40)
e2.config(show="*")
        
        
Button(root, text="Login", command=Ok ,height = 3, width = 13).place(x=10, y=100)
        
root.mainloop()
```

**Main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Main")
root.geometry("500x500")
global e1
global e2

Label(root, text="Welcome").place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt)

Comment: ya. can't we call two pages. we to design the same page login main menu also inorder to call.

Comment: You can import one file in the other file

Comment: how to import the file i don't know pls add the code

Comment: how to import the file in the other file  i don't know pls add the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) and please dont call your file `main.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Login.py

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

global e1
global e2

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("300x200")

def Ok():
    global e1, e2
    uname = e1.get()
    password = e2.get()

    if(uname == "" and password == "") :
        messagebox.showinfo("", "Blank Not allowed")
        return False


    elif(uname == "Admin" and password == "123"):

        messagebox.showinfo("","Login Success")
        os.system("python3 main.py")
        root.destroy()

        return True

    else :
        messagebox.showinfo("","Incorrent Username and Password")
        return False

Label(root, text="UserName").place(x=10, y=10)
Label(root, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)
Button(root, text="Login", command=Ok,height = 3, width = 13).place(x=10, y=100)

while True:


    global e1, e2
    e1 = Entry(root)
    e1.place(x=140, y=10)

    e2 = Entry(root)
    e2.place(x=140, y=40)
    e2.config(show="*")

    if Ok():
        os.system("python3 main_kinter.py")
        break

    root.mainloop()
```

`
and the main file :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Main")
root.geometry("500x500")
global e1
global e2

Label(root, text="Welcome").place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This as said, is not a very safe method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer on one of the ways on how to proceed. By importing the file onto another file.

**main.py:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import login

login.everything()

root = Tk()
root.title("Main")
root.geometry("500x500")

Label(root, text="Welcome").place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

**login.py:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def everything():
    def Ok():
        uname = e1.get()
        password = e2.get()

        if(uname == "" and password == "") :
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Blank Not allowed")


        elif(uname == "Admin" and password == "123"):

            messagebox.showinfo("","Login Success")
            top.destroy()
            main.destroy()

        else :
            messagebox.showinfo("","Incorrent Username and Password")
    main = Tk()
    main.withdraw()
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Login")
    top.geometry("300x200")

    Label(top, text="UserName").place(x=10, y=10)
    Label(top, text="Password").place(x=10, y=40)

    e1 = Entry(top)
    e1.place(x=140, y=10)

    e2 = Entry(top)
    e2.place(x=140, y=40)
    e2.config(show="*")


    Button(top, text="Login", command=Ok ,height = 3, width = 13).place(x=10, y=100)
    top.mainloop()
```

Hope you got an idea, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers