# CLOSED new Tk window opens automatically

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I had this exact same question :

[opening a new window with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt)

But as I ran the code given : (EDIT : first line is indeed from tkinter import *)

```
from tkinter import *

def create_window():
    window = Toplevel(root)

root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

the new window opens automatically, without waiting for the button to be clicked

why is that?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: e pur si muove!

I promise I didn't invent the case...  when i run the code,two windows are created.
The button creates a new one each time, but i d like just one window to start with

Comment: There is nothing in this code that will cause two windows to be created at startup. How are you running this code?

Comment: ok I think I got it.
Sorry.
using Jupyter, and it seems a previous cell was interfering :
top=Tk()

I didn't think, as it  is not the same name, that it would react that way.
Thank you for your comments