# In Tkinter, How to create a new window when a button is clicked on the previous screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, (Python), I want to add a button that creates a new window with some other widgets such as other buttons and Labels. How do I do that?

If I create a button as:

```py
Button(text = "click", command = new_window).pack()
```

So now what code should I use in the `new_window()` function in my program?

Comment: You can create a new window using `Toplevel` widget and then create other widgets inside that window the same as you create widgets in the root window.  Note that you did not specify the parent in your `Button(...)` example and it is not recommended.

Comment: The parent for Button(root) is root. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: Open a new window with a button prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Toplevel` for that.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Button

root = Tk()
root.title("Creating multiple windows")
root.geometry("500x500")

def new_window():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Second window")
    top.geometry("400x500")    # By default, it is kept as the geometry of the main window, but you can change it.
    lab = Label(top, text="This is second window!")
    lab.pack(pady=20)

l = Label(root, text="This is the first window")
l.pack(pady=20)

b = Button(root, text="Create new window", command=new_window)
b.pack(pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not recommended to run `mainloop()` more than once.

Comment: It is better to not use `root2` or similar names because it gets confusing whether it is a new window or a TopLevel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “Toplevel” widget for that.
Here’s how you can do that:

```
from tkinter import *
# NOTE: You can replace the variable names with your own

# Defining a function for a new window to appear
def new_window():
    # You can also customize this toplevel with similar attributes 
    new_toplevel = Toplevel()

# Creating the main GUI
root = Tk()
# You can customize the root window with attributes like .title(), .iconbitmap(), .geometry() etc.
new_button = Button(text=“New Window”, command=new_window)
new_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10) # Paddings are optional and you can also use .grid() with slightly different arguments
root.mainloop()
```