# Opening a New Window If No Messageboxes Pop Up - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

So I want my "Sign Up" button to open the verification page for my program if my signing up page won't make any message boxes pop up. I didn't include the "Sign Up" button in the code below but my general problem is that I need to open another window if no message boxes pop up. Here's the code:

```
    errors = [messagebox.showerror("Seperate!", "Please make sure you left a space between your name(s) and surname."),
              messagebox.showerror("Existed", "User already exists, please sign in."),
              messagebox.showerror("Characters", "Please make sure that your username doesn't have any uppercase letters or special characters e.g. '*','!',' ' etc."),
              messagebox.showerror("Length", "Please make sure that your username's length is no more than 20 characters."),
              messagebox.showerror("Fill the username!", "Please make sure that you entered your username."),
              messagebox.showerror("Syntax", """Please make sure that your password meets the following:
    Your password should contain:
    1. At least one digit (0-9),
    2. At least one symbol ('!','?','*' etc.),
    3. At least one uppercase letter (A-Z), 
    4. At least one lowercase letter (a-z)
        """),
              messagebox.showerror("Length", "Please make sure your password is of 8 to 20 characters."),
              messagebox.showerror("Syntax", "Please make sure your e-mail address is in the correct format."),
              messagebox.showerror("Fill e-mail!","Please fill in your e-mail address."),
              messagebox.showerror("Fill the input fields!", "Please make sure that you filled all necessary information.")
]
    for Error in range(0, len(errors)):
         error = errors[Error] 

    if error == False:
        verification_page()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need the `Toplevel()` widget.  Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639298/tkinter-open-a-new-window-with-a-button-prompt)